# Why My program Return String Value in XML format?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I am using a Web service and it returns a String value. But in my output, that value is in XML format:

```
String point = request.getParameter("point");
try {
  String latLonListCityNames = proxy.latLonListCityNames(new BigInteger(point));
  request.setAttribute("point", latLonListCityNames);
  System.out.println(latLonListCityNames);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I expect the output to be for example "Oklahoma", but the actual output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<dwml version='1.0' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
    <latLonList>
    <cityNameList>
        Oklahoma
    </cityNameList>
</dwml>
```

Comment: Is your `proxy.latLonListCityNames` is a web service call?

Comment: Try to change "Accept" as plain text/plain and check

Comment: the issue is under proxy.latLonListCityNames

Comment: @miiiii  yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The responses of web-services are commonly (not always) in XML. If you need to extract the data from xml string response to your desired format, say, Java Objects (POJO), you need a converter i.e. marshaling and Un-marshaling of data.

**Simple solution**

Use `JAXB`.

What is `JAXB`? [From wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding)

> Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) is a software framework that allows Java developers to map Java classes to XML representations. JAXB provides two main features: the ability to marshal Java objects into XML and the inverse, i.e. to unmarshal XML back into Java objects.

**How does it fit into my use-case?**

Create a simple [POJO](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pojo-vs-java-beans/) for the type of response you are expecting. And then use JAXB convertor to convert them for you.

Eg. If you are expecting a list of `cityName` in response, you can create your POJO like below..

**CityModel.java**

```
public Class CityModel {
    private List<String> cityName;
    // if more field required, add here.
}
```

Sample XML response should be..

```
<ListOfCities>
    <CityName>My City</CityName>
    <CityName>Your City</CityName>
    <CityName>So Pity</CityName>
</ListOfCities>
```

Then, pass this xml response string to JAXB binding for Equivalent Class type. i.e. `CityModel`.

**How to do all this? Can You Share some good example?**

Read [this tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/read-xml-to-java-object/) to get started.

**I have problem with the response type names, they are not well described, how can I map them with different name that I want?**

You might need to look at links below, they key part is investigate more about `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlAttribute`, `@XmlElement`, etc annotations for custom configurations.

**Few more important links that can help later on?**

[Convert Soap XML response to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333185/convert-soap-xml-response-to-object)

[convert xml to java object using jaxb (unmarshal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221136/convert-xml-to-java-object-using-jaxb-unmarshal)

[Using JAXB for XML With Java](https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-for-xml-with-java)

[JAXB Unmarshalling Example: Converting XML into Object](https://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example)